# UIWebView cache refresh/flush frequency

Tags: html, ios, caching, uiwebview, ios9

I have an app that loads a remote `HTML` page, from a `https://` location, in a `UIWebView`. The problem is that the `HTML` page is loaded, but it is a cached version. I forgot to turn off the cache. I need the users to see the latest version of the `HTML` page.

My questions are:

1. Does the `UIWebView` clear its cache regularly? If so, how often is this? (If this is the case, then I don't really have to worry. My users will eventually see the new page.)
2. If the `UIWebView` does not clear it's cache, is there a way I can force it to reload by changing some settings on my `HTML` page?
3. Or is releasing a whole new version, with cache-clearing, the only solution to my problem?
4. Also, this problem occurred on 2 `iOS 9` devices. I don't have access to a device with `iOS 8` so I'm not sure if this problem occurs there as well. Could this be an issue related to `iOS 9`? I know that they have some web security updates in it.

The current version of the app on the app store is built with the `iOS8 SDK`.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can't get it to load any new html, I don't think there is a html option available. If you can, then you could try to use js:  `location.reload();` . In my experience, UIWebview reloades when the app has been completely shut down, not just running in background.

Comment: @mark I tried killing the app and relaunching it and that did not work. It kept loading the cached version. I tested it on the browser and on the Android version of the app, and both times the latest version of the HTML file was loaded. Also, this was on an iOS9 device. Could this be specific to iOS9?

Comment: if you are testing on wifi, have you tested over cellular, or vice versa?

Comment: Tried that right now. No change. Problem still persists.